# How to sort data from API data in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Im trying to sort the data from api to Ascending & Descending inside **Datatable Widget** i follow the code and implementation however it doesn't work in my end Im using **FutureBuilder** to call the data any idea and help will be appreciated.

kindly see the link i post it to my personal github account as i have struggle to post the code here is the link : https://github.com/shanjoh/sorting-code/tree/6029c07e53921e96c8b6d6e218329e13246d2370

Answer (score 0):

if you store value like this

```
    `List<YourModel> sortdata =  snapshot.data!.sort((a, b) => -a.ccy.compareTo(b.ccy));`
```

then you assign sortData in your card

Comment: its void value sir its value can't be used

Comment: then you compare with wrong value. 
you can sort by two ways.
1. server side send you data in sorting order.
2. in client side, compare with numeric value of api data

Comment: can i get the correct data using this ' List<Model> sortData = <Model>[]; ' ?

Comment: initialy sortData will be empty this like ' List<Model> sortData = []; '.